# A question related to UI Refresh

Tags: iphone

I  have  question  related  to  what  is  done in SMS  application  is  if i'm in inbox and during the reading of message if 1 more message opens  then  the latest message will be updated and then show it on top

how to do it??
can anyone give me code of it.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.  Are you asking about how to replicate the SMS application's user interface?

Comment: You've asked 20 questions but have accepted 0 answers. Unless absolutely none of those answered helped you, please go back through your previous questions and fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the blueish overlay thing, you can implement it via Push Notifications or a UIAlertView.

If you mean the screen with the entire conversation, implement it using a UIScrollView and update when a new message comes in.